# Is this design correct? How can I improve it?

Tags: motor, embedded, design, mosfet-driver, esp32

I designed this circuit to control a total of 4 motors via a web interface hosted on the ESP32.

[image: My design]

The bridge is simply a 0 ohm resistor needed to activate the motor driver.
The L80-M39 is an integrated antenna GPS module, while U1 is a LDO.

In general, is the design correct? How can I improve it?

Comment: > engines <br> "motors", not "engines". In English, an engine is powered by fuel (petrol) while a motor is powered by electricity. While the design looks fine, I'd ask you to please draw your circuit per the conventions, to make it more readable. Specifically, draw the Q1 and Q4 sections just like you drew the Q2 and Q3 sections. Also, please add legends to tell us what each IC does. Especially the L80-M39.

Comment: Try and use standard orientations and positioning in your schematics. It's not as bad as some I've seen. It shows some effort, but enough effort has been shown that there is no reason for the components to be arranged inconsistently. I am mainly referring to the bottom right. You have plenty of white space above that you can use.

Comment: Your 3.3V regulator might get rather toasty. For 12V input i’d suggest a buck converter.  In addition to the other’s comments, draw you pullups/pulldowns attached to whatever they are pulling up or down. Makes the intention clear.